# Error: sets the total supply upon deployment

Tags: solidity, truffle

Please help !

When i try to run test from truffle, i got this problem, here my test js code:

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol")

contract(DappToken, function(accounts) {
    it ('sets the total supply upon deployment', function() {
        return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return tokenInstance.totalSupply();}).then(function(totalSupply){
                assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(), 1000000, "sets the total supply to 1000000");
            });
        });
    })
```

and here my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract DappToken {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function DToken () public {
        totalSupply = 1000000;
    }   
}
```

and here the result of the test:

[image: test contract truffle]

PS: for more information, I follow the instruction video "Code Your Own Cryptocurrency on Ethereum (Full)" from Dapp University chanel on youtube , at 40:03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here.

```
contract DappToken {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function DToken () public { <----
        totalSupply = 1000000;
    }   
}
```

I suppose you meant it to be the constructor. Since the version `0.4.22` of Solidity, you have to design the constructor with a special keyword `constructor`. So it becomes like that :

```
contract DappToken {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
     constructor() public {
        totalSupply = 1000000;
    }   
}
```

Comment: may i ask, Is the constructor in solidity as same meaning as constructor in javascript ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I just a newbie and not native english speaker, i don't know how to explain my problem clearly. I got another problem and the answer like this again, so i think I lack some basic knowledge about programming language to fully understand this line  [i] "Since the version 0.4.22 of Solidity, you have to design the constructor with a special keyword constructor" [/i]

Comment: It means you have to use the word `constructor` as the function's name for the constructor, just like in the example I put in my answer.